# How to insert values from another table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, subquery, parameterized-query

I have a table which references other tables:

```
CREATE TABLE scratch
(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  rep_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES reps,
  term_id INT REFERENCES terms
);
CREATE TABLE reps (
  id    SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  rep   TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
CREATE TABLE terms (
  id    SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  terms TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

I wish to add a new record to scratch given the **name**, the **rep** and the **terms** values, i.e. I have neither corresponding **rep_id** nor **term_id**.

Right now the only idea that I have is:

```
insert into scratch (name, rep_id, term_id)
             values ('aaa', (select id from reps where rep='Dracula' limit 1), (select id from terms where terms='prepaid' limit 1));
```

My problem is this. I am trying to use the parameterized query API (from node using the node-postgres package), where an insert query looks like this:

```
insert into scratch (name, rep_id, term_id) values ($1, $2, $3);
```

and then an array of values for $1, $2 and $3 is passed as a separate argument. At the end, when I am comfortable with the parameterized queries the idea is to promote them to prepared statements to utilize the most efficient and safest way to query the database.

However, I am puzzled how can I do this with my example, where different tables have to be subqueried.

P.S. I am using PostgreSQL 9.2 and have no problem with a PostgreSQL specific solution.

**EDIT 1**

```
C:\Users\markk>psql -U postgres
psql (9.2.4)
WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from Windows code page (1252)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \c dummy
WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from Windows code page (1252)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
You are now connected to database "dummy" as user "postgres".
dummy=# DROP TABLE scratch;
DROP TABLE
dummy=# CREATE TABLE scratch
dummy-# (
dummy(#   id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
dummy(#   name text NOT NULL UNIQUE,
dummy(#   rep_id integer NOT NULL,
dummy(#   term_id integer
dummy(# );
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "scratch_id_seq" for serial column "scratch.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "scratch_pkey" for table "scratch"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / UNIQUE will create implicit index "scratch_name_key" for table "scratch"
CREATE TABLE
dummy=# DEALLOCATE insert_scratch;
ERROR:  prepared statement "insert_scratch" does not exist
dummy=# PREPARE insert_scratch (text, text, text) AS
dummy-# INSERT INTO scratch (name, rep_id, term_id)
dummy-# SELECT $1, r.id, t.id
dummy-# FROM reps r, terms t
dummy-# WHERE r.rep = $2 AND t.terms = $3
dummy-# RETURNING id, name, $2 rep, $3 terms;
PREPARE
dummy=# DEALLOCATE insert_scratch2;
ERROR:  prepared statement "insert_scratch2" does not exist
dummy=# PREPARE insert_scratch2 (text, text, text) AS
dummy-# INSERT INTO scratch (name, rep_id, term_id)
dummy-#              VALUES ($1, (SELECT id FROM reps WHERE rep=$2 LIMIT 1), (SELECT id FROM terms WHERE terms=$3 LIMIT 1))
dummy-# RETURNING id, name, $2 rep, $3 terms;
PREPARE
dummy=# EXECUTE insert_scratch ('abc', 'Snowhite', '');
 id | name | rep | terms
----+------+-----+-------
(0 rows)


INSERT 0 0
dummy=# EXECUTE insert_scratch2 ('abc', 'Snowhite', '');
 id | name |   rep    | terms
----+------+----------+-------
  1 | abc  | Snowhite |
(1 row)


INSERT 0 1
dummy=# EXECUTE insert_scratch ('abcd', 'Snowhite', '30 days');
 id | name |   rep    |  terms
----+------+----------+---------
  2 | abcd | Snowhite | 30 days
(1 row)


INSERT 0 1
dummy=# EXECUTE insert_scratch2 ('abcd2', 'Snowhite', '30 days');
 id | name  |   rep    |  terms
----+-------+----------+---------
  3 | abcd2 | Snowhite | 30 days
(1 row)


INSERT 0 1
dummy=#
```

**EDIT 2**

We can utilize the fact that `rep_id` is required, even though `terms_id` is optional and use the following version of INSERT-SELECT:

```
PREPARE insert_scratch (text, text, text) AS
INSERT INTO scratch (name, rep_id, term_id)
SELECT $1, r.id, t.id
FROM reps r
LEFT JOIN terms t ON t.terms = $3
WHERE r.rep = $2
RETURNING id, name, $2 rep, $3 terms;
```

This version, however, has two problems:

1. No distinction is made between a missing `terms` value (i.e. '') and an invalid `terms` value (i.e. a non empty value missing from the terms table entirely). Both are treated as missing terms. (But the INSERT with two subqueries suffers from the same problem)
2. The version depends on the fact that the `rep` is required. But what if `rep_id` was optional too?

**EDIT 3**

Found the solution for the item 2 - eliminating dependency on rep being required. Plus using the WHERE statement has the problem that the sql does not fail if the rep is invalid - it just inserts 0 rows, whereas I want to fail explicitly in this case. My solution is simply using a dummy one row CTE:

```
PREPARE insert_scratch (text, text, text) AS
WITH stub(x) AS (VALUES (0))
INSERT INTO scratch (name, rep_id, term_id)
SELECT $1, r.id, t.id
FROM stub
LEFT JOIN terms t ON t.terms = $3
LEFT JOIN reps r ON r.rep = $2
RETURNING id, name, rep_id, term_id;
```

If rep is missing or invalid, this sql will try to insert NULL into the rep_id field and since the field is `NOT NULL` an error would be raised - precisely what I need. And if further I decide to make rep optional - no problem, the same SQL works for that too.

Comment: Why would it even consider inserting nothing a succesful operation? Is such behavior documented anywhere? I also need an explicit error to be thrown, when it does that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
INSERT into scratch (name, rep_id, term_id)
SELECT 'aaa'
        , r.id 
        , t.id
FROM reps r , terms t -- essentially a cross join
WHERE r.rep = 'Dracula'
  AND t.terms = 'prepaid'
        ;
```

Notes:

- You don't need the ugly `LIMIT`s, since r.rep and t.terms are unique (candidate keys)
- you could replace the `FROM a, b` by a `FROM a CROSS JOIN b`
- the `scratch` table will probably need an `UNIQUE` constraint `on (rep_id, term_it)` (the nullability of `term_id` is questionable)

UPDATE: the same as prepared query [as found in the Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-prepare.html)

```
PREPARE hoppa (text, text,text) AS
        INSERT into scratch (name, rep_id, term_id)
        SELECT $1 , r.id , t.id
        FROM reps r , terms t -- essentially a cross join
        WHERE r.rep = $2
        AND t.terms = $3
        ;
EXECUTE hoppa ('bbb', 'Dracula' , 'prepaid' );

SELECT * FROM scratch;
```

UPDATE2: test data

```
DROP SCHEMA tmp CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA tmp ;
SET search_path=tmp;

CREATE TABLE reps ( id    SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, rep   TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE terms ( id    SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, terms TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE scratch ( id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT NOT NULL, rep_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES reps, term_id INT REFERENCES terms);

INSERT INTO  reps(rep) VALUES( 'Dracula' );
INSERT INTO  terms(terms) VALUES( 'prepaid' );
```

Results:

```
NOTICE:  drop cascades to 3 other objects
DETAIL:  drop cascades to table tmp.reps
drop cascades to table tmp.terms
drop cascades to table tmp.scratch
DROP SCHEMA
CREATE SCHEMA
SET
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
PREPARE
INSERT 0 1
 id | name | rep_id | term_id 
----+------+--------+---------
  1 | aaa  |      1 |       1
  2 | bbb  |      1 |       1
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Could you change your example to utilize the `PREPARE` statement? I would like to see how your example looks like with $1, $2, ...

Comment: For some strange reason this INSERT with SELECT does not insert anything for me. Have you checked it on an actual PostgreSQL database?

Comment: Well, I do not understand what is going on. Please, examine **EDIT 1** to my post, containing a psql session where one can see that the INSERT-SELECT version does nothing, whereas the INSERT with two subqueries works as expected. I will be glad to know what is the problem.

Comment: You should not pass the parameters` $1 $2 $3 ` as an array, but as separate arguments (just like calling a function) see my example code : `EXECUTE hoppa ('bbb', 'Dracula' , 'prepaid' );`

Comment: Oops, just noticed that I forgot to post the **EDIT 1**. Did it now.

Comment: Aha code page/encoding  woes .... `SET client_encoding = 1251;` (or something like that) at the top of your SQL script. (or restrict your character strings to ASCII-only)

Comment: You are expanding the question. Please don't do that. My answer works, if you have difficulty expanding that to a complete CRM system, than that is your problem. Good luck.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand how am I expanding the question. I might be doing it unknowingly, of course. Could you be more specific and point out the problem with my example? Is it because of the other fields? Well, they were always in the scratch table, I just thought they were irrelevant and omitted them for brevity when I posted the question. You think they are relavant after all? I will retest without them and update my **EDIT 1**.

Comment: OK, I have removed all the additional fields, they really do not matter. Apparently, what matters is that the `terms` value is optional. The INSERT-SELECT as given does not work when the `terms` value is missing, whereas the INSERT with two subqueries - does work. The `terms_id` is specified as optional from the very beginning, so there is no expansion of the question. Unfortunally, the nullability of terms_id is a given and not questionable.

Comment: You'll have to fully qualify the terms in the `RETURNING` clause (`id` is not unique). IIRC `RETURNING` can only reference the affected table. (the `lvalue` in C-speak)

Comment: The `id` thing does not matter, because there is no ambiguity - no other table has the column `id`. Plus no row is truly created, regardless of the RETURNING statement. I added the latter in order to spare me the need to invoke a separate SELECT statement to check the insert.

Comment: I have just credited your reply, because it contains enough to answer my question - see **EDIT 2**. It could be a perfect reply (with extra +1) if it addressed the two questions raised in the edit.